# How to Shutdown Compute Node in Openstack if no SSH Access

Tags: server, cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

I need some advise and comment...
I'm not able to ssh access compute node in openstack and due to that not able to perform shutdown. Any other proper way to shutdown the server if this is the case... I'm thinking of shutdown/reboot via idrac but not sure if this is a good without broken any openstack system.
Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openstack doesn't have a way to control (e.g. shut down) the compute node.

If you are concerned about the instances running on the compute node, they can be shutdown via the horizon dashboard, the openstack client or the nova client.  Do this before you shutdown the compute node via the idrac.

Comment: Noted and thank you. Due to the problem most of the instances in error state and not able to shutdown via dashboard. Resolution is to shutdown/reboot the compute via idrac and re-activate the instances once normalize. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

To shutdown the compute node gracefuly, you have to access the ilo/idrac/ipmi console and then open the remote console session. Once remote console is open, then you can gracefully shutdown the compute node from there.

Another option is shutdown the compute node from openstack itself using openstack baremetal node power off .

Comment: Thanks tamjid....i think the best way is to properly shutdwn via openstack...just the case now...it can be done via openstack... so the only option is via ilo/idrac... my concern if using idrac shutdwn it will crash system binding between openstack and servers... i mean...after reboot...d instances or even the server somehow would not able to be part of compute nodes...

Answer (score 0):

do you have a shared storage? You could migrate the vms from the compute node to another compute node.

Then perform the graceful shutdown from ipmi